# How to knit single files in a bookdown project without serving the whole book. Is there an equivalent to `options(blogdown.knit.serve_site=FALSE)`?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, bookdown

For reasons similar to those in [blogdown issue 572](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/572), I would like the Rstudio knit button to behave as it does when I am not in a bookdown project folder, rendering a file that happens to be in a bookdown project folder according to the file's YAML, not the bookdown output YAML. I think this means that I would like the knit button to call `rmarkdown::render` rather than `rmarkdown::render_site`.

As noted by Yihui in [blogdown issue 572](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/572#issuecomment-763894040), there is now such an option to change the default behavior of the knit button in a blogdown project: `options(blogdown.knit.serve_site = FALSE)`.

The bookdown [docs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-knit.html) show how to customize the knit button:

```
knit: (function(input, ...) {rmarkdown::render(input)})
```

This works, but I'd rather change the global options for the Knit button, if possible (because we have a "Build Book" button in the Build pane. Thanks!